# Cant pass canvas image as byte array javafx

Tags: javafx, canvas, byte

I want to pass java canvas image as byte array and then draw it again on canvas, i tried this, but buffer is like -1,-1,-8,-16,-1,-1,-8,-16,... and then when i convert byte array to image it has 0 width and height

```
WritableImage image = new WritableImage((int) drawCanvas.getWidth(), (int) drawCanvas.getHeight());
drawCanvas.snapshot(null, image);
byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) (drawCanvas.getWidth() * drawCanvas.getHeight() * 4)];
image.getPixelReader().getPixels(0,
        0,
        (int) drawCanvas.getWidth(),
        (int) drawCanvas.getHeight(),
        PixelFormat.getByteBgraInstance(),
        buffer,
        0,
        (int) drawCanvas.getWidth() * 4
);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buffer));

Image image1 = new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));
System.out.println(image1.getWidth());
gc.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, image1.getWidth(), image1.getHeight());
```

gc is drawCanvas GraphicsContext

Comment: Your `buffer` is the raw pixel data. I'm not sure that the `Image(InputStream)` constructor can handle that; I believe it expects one of the supported image formats (e.g., JPEG, PNG, etc.). Maybe you could create a new `WritableImage` and use its `PixelWriter` to set its pixels to the values held in `buffer`, then call `drawImage` with that `WritableImage`.

Comment: There's no way this could actually work, because all you are providing to the `Image` constructor is pixel data. The dimensions of the image, for example, are not defined by this. Even if you assume the format (4 bytes per pixel in BGRA format), a stream of (for example) 8000 bytes would represent 2000 pixels, which could be 20x100, 25x80, 40x50 or many other dimensions. As suggested, create a new `WritableImage` of the required dimensions, and use `getPixelWriter().setPixels(...)`.